# How to avoid conflicting when naming model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to know if there is a best to name model attribute that won't conflict with `ActiveRecord::Base` instance methods.

For example, we probably won't name attribute as `class` or `toggle`, since these names have already been taken. But how do I simply know if the name is conflicted when generating a model? Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750009/reserved-names-with-activerecord-models.

Answer (score 3):

Fire your console at first

```
 > a = MyModel.new
 > a.methods.grep(/my_attr/)
```

If nothing, nice, you can use my_attr