# Are 'fields' and 'types' allowed names for rails postgresql tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to name my tables in postgresql as 'fields' and 'types', to be used in a rails 4 (ActiveRecord) app - are these kinds of common words acceptable as names, or will they clash with rails or postgresql reserved names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of: [Reserved names with ActiveRecord models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750009/reserved-names-with-activerecord-models)

Here is additional info regarding reserved words in postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Ultimately, the answer is no, 'fields' is not a reserved name for rails or postgres; however, 'types' may cause some problems. Type is an ActionView method per the following: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Template.html#method-i-type

Comment: I noticed in the rails reserved link in the other SO thread you linked, that the word `type` is listed as reserved. If I have a types table and use type in the singular across rails, could that cause any trouble?

Comment: My fault. Yes, you are right. I'll revise my answer.